# Why is Luke Skywalker wearing a glove in Episode IX?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, the-rise-of-skywalker

A scene from Episode IX depicts Luke Skywalker (presumably a Force ghost) wearing a glove. Why does his Force ghost have a missing hand?

Comment: I’ve flagged this as primarily opinion-based in accordance with our [Future Works Policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11865/102999).

Comment: why would Ghost Kenobi look like an old-man in RotJ, rather than his younger self? Either your ghost projection is as you were when you "died" (which was the justification for adding Haydn in RotJ), or you project in a form most likely to be recognized by those seeing you. If young Kenobi appeared to Luke in RoTJ, Luke may have been taken even more aback: "Who are you, exactly?", rather than simply saying "Obi-Wan!"

Comment: And where have you seen this "scene"? I can't find anything on it, other than a single photo, not any video. The photo shows Luke in the flesh next to R2-D2, not as a ghost. It is likely in a flashback.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen the scene, but there are two force ghosts named Skywalker who could be expected to wear a single glove for the same reason.

Count Dooku cut off Anakin Skywalker's hand, and Darth Vader cut off Luke Skywalker's hand. Both men had a mechanical hand, over which they would often wear a glove.

[image: Luke Skywalker][image: Anakin Skywalker]

Comment: The question as stated is a little ambiguous, but I believe the querent is asking what a *ghost,* which presumably has no mechanical components, would be hiding with a glove.

Comment: @RyanVeeder A ghost can totally have mechanical components.  http://www.galactanet.com/comic/view.php?strip=20 shows an example.